# Mongo DB server Fails to connect in Kubernetes using Helm charts

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a kubernetes cluster. I installed a mongodb pod using this link https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/master/stable/mongodb/README.md#configuration

But When I try to connect to the mongodb server it gives me the following error -

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x140c46e]
```

This is the command I am trying to run to access the server -

```
kubectl run mydb-mongodb-client --rm --tty -i --image bitnami/mongodb --command -- mongo --host mydb-mongodb -p password
```

Comment: `helm install --name my-db --set mongodbRootPassword=password,mongodbUsername=my-user,mongodbPassword=my-password,mongodbDatabase=my-database  stable/mongodb` is this the exact command you used to deploy mongodb?

Comment: Yeah that’s correct